# using awk in expect send getting can't read "1": no such variable error

Tags: awk, tcl, expect

I am sending awk command through expect send, when i am sending i am getting error but i  can't read 1 no such variable

I did use {{}} mechansim but i did work,

```
expect "$prompt" {
    send "awk {{print $1}} /mytest/test.log\r"
}
```

I tried with eascapse sequence \, but i didnot find any response expect_out(buffer),..etc

```
    expect "$prompt" {
    send "awk '{print \$1}' /mytest/test.log\r"
}
```

I tried with exec command also

```
    expect "$prompt" {
    send "exec awk {{print $1}} /mytest/test.log\r"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the curly braces to avoid substitution. Alternatively you have to escape the dollar sign and the curly braces too.

A couple of examples:

1. interacting with a program on your local machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d

spawn "/bin/bash"
set cmd "awk '\{print \$1\}' /mytest/test.log\r"
send $cmd
expect eof
puts $expect_out(buffer)
```

2. interacting with a remote program over ssh:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d

append cmd {awk '{print $1}' /mytest/test.log} "\r"
spawn ssh user@hostname
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "mypassword\r"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send $cmd
send "exit\r"
expect eof
puts $expect_out(buffer)
```